# Robotframework IntelliBot error How solve issue

Tags: robotframework, intellibot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Ynz.png)I need support with solve this issue. If someone face with similar problem ? In consol SeleniumLibrary is not visible and I got error like on picture below.

I change version of python, Pycharm and Selenium but nothing help.